# why I cant compare the timestamp in my sql database with the current time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

the sql table contains the time which is saved in timestamp
[the format of time looks like this 2017-04-17 13:00:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQcWI.png)

```
  <?php
  include 'con.php';
  $token = $_GET['key'];
  $sql = "Select * FROM userlogin WHERE token = '$token'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if($user['time'] > 1800) {          // check if the time is greater than 30 minutes then the link will expire.
     exit("Link has expired");
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: time will be in which format, can you update your question with that ?

Comment: it is saved in sql using timestamp and it looks like this 2017-04-17 13:00:00 @rahul_m

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Paste this code in your head section and replace anyone.com with your site url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if("<?php echo $timezone; ?>".length==0){
            var visitortime = new Date();
            var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://anyone.com/timezone.php",
                data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
                success: function(){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And Create a new file timezone.php and write there

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['time'] = $_GET['time'];
?>
```

And start the session in your header

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

When you save userdetails to  db add a new field like gmttime and insert 
$timezone  value .

```
$timezone = $_SESSION['time'];
```

Also add jquery in your header

The new code will be

```
 <?php
      include 'con.php';
      $token = $_GET['key'];
      $sql = "Select * FROM userlogin WHERE token = '$token'";
      $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
      $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      $time = $user['time'];
      $gmt  = $user['gmttime'];

       $timezone2 = str_replace("GMT", "", $gmt);

       $sec = 3600 * $timezone2;

      $gmtdate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      $current_time =  date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($gmtdate) + ($sec)); 

      $user_time = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time) + 1800 ); 




      if($current_time > $user_time) {          // check if the current time is greater than $user['time']+30 minutes
         exit("Link has expired");
      }
      else{
      //your code part here
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: if($current_time > $user_time) { echo $current_time ."\n".$user_time; } // I tried to echo it but the results are 2017-04-17 10:20:53 2017-04-17 15:37:25 the usertime is correct but the current time is wrong how can I change it? @Sandeep

Comment: Did you set your date default timezone?

Comment: No, I don't want a default timezone, it'll be stored in a database for every user how will i do that?

Comment: And your $user_time and $current_time should be in same time zone @janejoe

Comment: How will I do that? @Sandeep

Comment: Do you need current time according to user location? @janejoe

Comment: Yes thats what I need @Sandeep

Comment: current_time is this 2017-04-18 07:36:28 and $user_time is this 2017-04-18 13:30:00 looks like its 6 hours late? what's wrong @Sandeep

Comment: I echo the $timezone and it shows GMT + 8 which is correct but the time showing up is not correct. @Sandeep

Comment: Did you save user_time according to user location?@janejoe

Comment: user_time must be saved according to GMT+8 @janejoe

Answer (score 0):

@janejoe you are missing something just correct your condition like:

```
 <?php
  include 'con.php';
  $token = $_GET['key'];
  $sql = "Select * FROM userlogin WHERE token = '$token'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $limitTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($user['time']) + 1800);
  if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") > $limitTime) {          // check if the time is greater than 30 minutes then the link will expire.
    echo "current date time :". date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     exit("Link has expired");
  }
?>
```

Comment: same thing happens if(time() > $limitTime) { echo $current_time ."\n".$user_time; } // I tried to echo it but the results are 2017-04-17 10:30:27 2017-04-17 16:58:55 the $limitTime is correct but the current time() is wrong. @Bunker Boy

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in MySQL.

```
  <?php
  include 'con.php';

  $token = $_GET['key'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE token = '$token' AND time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) AND TIMESTAMP(NOW())";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  if (!mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    exit("Link has expired");
  }

  $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  // etc.
  ?>
```